# Get the iframe height from the javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, plugins

I have a iframe tag embedded in the webpage similar to

```
  <iframe id="xyz" height="900" width="800" src="www.pqr.com></iframe>

I'm trying to get the height and width of the iframe using:
 function getDimensions()
{
    var iframelist = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for(var i=0;i<iframelist.length;i++)
    {
     if(iframelist[i].id == "xyz")
    {
      var width = iframelist[i].height;
      var height = iframelist[i].width;
      var src = iframelist[i].src;
    }
    }
}
```

i am getting 0 value for width and height but src is getting proper values.

I am inserting the above javascript function defination into the webpage using  NPN_Evaluate() function and again calling the function using the NPN_evaluate.

Help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you need to close the `src` attribute `src="www.pqr.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like this..

```
var iframelist = document.getElementById("xyz");
alert(iframelist.offsetHeight​);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dQjqR/

Or are you trying to access dimensions from within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working here on this demo, which browser are you testing it on?

[DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/ouitocy3/0)

Comment: I am running  this code on IE and Firefox browser. i'm injecting the above javascript code into webpage using NPN_Evaluate() function from my NPAPI plugin as i mentioned above.